# fix the "Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed)." in vue2 project to create new user

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

when I want to create a new user, I face these errors:
1-Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).
2-access to fetch at 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyDfU.....' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
[image]

> signup.vue

```js
import{ app} from '@/firebase/firebase'
import {  getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

export default {
  name: 'signUp',

  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      name: null,
      lastname: null,
      email: '',
      password: '',

  
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  }, methods: {
    async signup() {
    
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword( getAuth(app), this.email, this.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed 'in' 
          alert(userCredential)
          //const user = userCredential.user;
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
            alert('weak pass')
          } else {
            alert(errorMessage)
          }
         
        });


    }
  },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="myform">
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="6" class="offset-3">

      
        <v-text-field clearable dark  v-model="email" label="email" required>
        </v-text-field>
        <v-text-field clearable dark v-model="password" label="password" required>
        </v-text-field>

        <v-btn class="mr-4" @click="signup" title="sign">
          register
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn>
          logIn
        </v-btn>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

> firebase.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: " ",
  authDomain: " ",
  projectId: " ",
  storageBucket: " m",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: " "
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const dbase = getFirestore(app)
```